# Relative url mapping for images in django imagefield

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-models

I am using imagefield to render images. These are the urls;

```
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': site_media}),
    (r'^$', 'webapp.blog.views.index'),
    url(
        r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', 
        'webapp.blog.views.view_post', 
        name='view_blog_post'),
```

These are the views:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:5]
    })

def view_post(request, slug):   
    return render_to_response('view_post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug),
    })
```

If I call a image object in the index page with `{{ posts.photos.url }}` it properly maps to `http://127.0.0.1/site_media/images/image.jpg`. But if I call the image object on view_post template it gets mapped to `http://127.0.0.1/blog/view/site_media/images/image.jpg`. How can I make `view_post` function map image urls to the proper `http://127.0.0.1/site_media/images/image.jpg` url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a function of your urlconf, but how you are displaying the images in your template. You are probably doing something like this:

```
<img src="site_media/images/image.jpg">
```

when you should be doing

```
<img src="/site_media/images/image.jpg">
```

... note the initial slash. Alternatively, if you're using STATIC_URL or MEDIA_URL, make sure they're defined with the initial slash in your settings.py.

Comment: This solved the issue `<img title="" alt="" src="/{{ post.photo.url }}"></a>`